# Extension of arms in VR, problems with the Y direction Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, vector, virtual-reality

I am working on a Unity VR application for one of the professors in the local clinics. But I'm having some problems.

What I would like to achieve: I want to simulate in VR that the player's arms are longer than in reality. The pivot point for moving the arms is the player. I tried the Steam VR plugin and after some tinkering I managed to get it work on the x and the z axis. What I can't figure out is how to fix the offset on the y axis. If I apply the offset like i do it on the other axises, then the hands are higher than they supposed to be. Steam VR returns a transform that shows the current position of the arms and I modify this with the pre set offset. I tried to figure out the math, but no luck so far. The ideal scenario would be: the y offset only happens when the player starts to raise their hands and when it fully over the head then we apply the full offset. My best guess is watching the rotation, and apply the offset based on the rotation percentage, but I have the feeling that there is a better way to do this. Anyone has a better solution?

Thank you

Comment: I mean the math isn't too bad, you just take the difference from the camera to the hand and multiply...

Comment: If you don't get any usable solutions, you may want to draw up an image of what your goal scenario is, as well as an image of what is currently happening wrongly.